# Please add a category under "Questions" for "Recommended" questions for that user

Tags: feature-request, questions, search

I would like to have a category added under "questions" for "recommended" questions for that user. (Next to "newest", "active", etc.)

Our volumes are getting up there, and I don't want to have to check the site every 8 hours and manually sift through everything to see what I might be able to answer.

I think I'm one of those users that has shown that I am capable of contributing high-quality content, I just need some help with quickly identifying those questions that I am best suited to answer. If you want such people to contribute, it would really help to add this sort option to allow us to quickly identify the questions we should be focusing on.

FWIW, this is probably the biggest reason I haven't been active on the site lately. It just takes too much time to regularly sift through all the new stuff to find something relevant to my areas of expertise.

The section should be filtered and sorted based on the users favorite tags, with newer questions listed closer to the top, or perhaps those with the fewest votes on answers, or something to this effect.

Simply navigating via the current "Tags" category (next to "Questions" at the top) gives me all sorts of Q's that I don't need to be focusing on, either because they are very, very old, or because they already have high-voted, accepted answers. (This route also gives me questions I don't want to see because they include other tags that I am not interested in. Hypothetical example: a question with both "hermeneutics" and "catechism" tags.)

Comment: @waxeagle Either I was smoking something, can no longer find the feature, or it's been removed. I edited the question. I may have been thinking of the "extra tweaking" you mentioned.

Comment: I just have a bunch of tags marked as "favorite tags", and clicking on them filters to questions with those tags. Clicking on multiple "favorite tags" adds multiple tag filters. As I remember, filtered questions are displayed in descending date order. Is that something like what you need, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Within your list of questions in that favourite tag, you still have "Newest", "Active" and so on. So you can click a tag and then "Newest" to get the newest questions in that tag.

Comment: It's still an aweful lot of searching and sorting. Seems like it would make more sense to just show the user the questions they need to see based on the tags, date, and lack of adequate existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

This feature already exists through the the umbrella [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) portal site. You can use the [filtered questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters) page to setup one or more custom feeds of questions. The easiest way to get stated is by marking tags on your sites as "favorited", then use the predefined feed there to see a list of questions just from your favorited tags. However you can take it a step further by adding additional feeds with custom groups of tags from your choice of sites.

Comment: This feature is no different than searching through the tags. There is no consideration given to whether the questions are newer, whether they already have high-voted / accepted answers, whether they contain tags I don't want to see...

Comment: @Jas3.1 You might have to make a custom query against the API. Check what you can find on stackapps.